# UIMA Ruta version 3.1.0

Tags: uima, ruta

I've upgraded the Uima Ruta version to 3.1.0 in Ruta Workbench.
I tried with normal Ruta project its working fine but while convert into maven project i'm getting below error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.AnalysisEngineProcessException: The JCAS cover class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.TokenSeed_Type" could not be loaded.
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.seedAnnotations(RutaEngine.java:947)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.initializeStream(RutaEngine.java:906)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.process(RutaEngine.java:692)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_component.JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.process(JCasAnnotator_ImplBase.java:48)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.callAnalysisComponentProcess(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:401)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.processAndOutputNewCASes(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:318)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.process(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:269)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.processFile(RutaLauncher.java:242)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.ide.launching.RutaLauncher.main(RutaLauncher.java:191)
Caused by: org.apache.uima.cas.CASRuntimeException: The JCAS cover class "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.TokenSeed_Type" could not be loaded.
    at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getTypeInit(JCasImpl.java:461)
    at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getType(JCasImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getCasType(JCasImpl.java:478)
    at org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl.getAnnotationIndex(JCasImpl.java:1634)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.seed.TextSeeder.seed(TextSeeder.java:43)
    at org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaEngine.seedAnnotations(RutaEngine.java:945)
    ... 8 more
```

**Note:**I'm using Eclipse version 2019-09 and java 1.8.

Thanks in advance
ScreenShot FYI:
[image: UIMA 3.2.0]

Comment: Are you trying to use Ruta in conjunction with UIMA version 2? Ruta version 3 is only compatible with UIMA version 3. Ruta 3.1.0 should be used together with UIMA 3.2.0.

Comment: I'm using UIMA 3.2.0 with Ruta 3.1.0 only.

Comment: @prasanth Did you face any issue post upgrading ruta to 3x version.
Is all your ruta scripts working?
During update of uima ruta 2x version to 3x version any special steps need to take care.

Comment: @prasanth Can you help here if have some clue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784156/uima-ruta-migration-from-2x-version-to-3x-version

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there are two different versions of UIMA Ruta involved.

One version is the version of the Ruta Workbench as seen in the screenshot in the question.

When you run a Ruta script/analysis engine in maven context, then the classpath of the maven dependencies is the relevant one. This means that you are somewhat independent of the installed plugins if you develop a UIMA/Ruta based maven project.

In your case, I assume that there is an old ruta version in the maven dependencies. Or there are several and the old one wins.