# Uima ruta migration from 2x version to 3x version

Tags: uima, ruta

Entity extraction using Ruta scripts are not working post upgrading Uima and ruta to 3x version.
It was working fine with 2x versions and only JCas classes are upgraded to 3x version.
I did not find any exceptions but its not detecting any entities.

Any extra steps need to do for Ruta scripts during migration.

```
versions used:
[uimaj-3.4.1]
[uimafit-3.4.0]
[ruta-3.3.0]
[cleartk-3.0.0]
```

I am expecting any heads up which can help in debugging this and any steps that missed during migration.

I saw some error stack too:

at org.apache.uima.ruta.condition.PartOfCondition.check(PartOfCondition.java:80) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.condition.PartOfCondition.eval(PartOfCondition.java:52) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.condition.NotCondition.eval(NotCondition.java:37) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.condition.AndCondition.eval(AndCondition.java:42) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.doMatch(RutaRuleElement.java:381) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRuleElement.startMatch(RutaRuleElement.java:81) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.ComposedRuleElement.startMatch(ComposedRuleElement.java:79) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:72) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:63) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.rule.RutaRule.apply(RutaRule.java:42) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.block.RutaScriptBlock.apply(RutaScriptBlock.java:74) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.uima.ruta.RutaModule.apply(RutaModule.java:56) ~[ruta-core-3.3.0.jar:?]

Comment: @Peter Kluegl could you please help here

Comment: why anchors values are coming as null in ruta in ruta 3x version? @Peter Kluegl